# How can I move matching files into another directory?

Tags: linux, file, bash, shell

I need to move thousands of images:

```
/Directory/0000/000000.jpg
/Directory/..../.......jpg
/Directory/ZZZZ/ZZZZZZ.jpg
```

to a flat directory:

```
/Directory/000000.jpg
/Directory/.......jpg
/Directory/ZZZZZZ.jpg
```

How can I do this?

Essentially I'm looking for something like this:  (but, you know, actually works)

```
mv -r /Directory/*/*.jpg /Directory
```

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, why doesn't your `mv` command work?  Unless you have different numbers of subdirectories (like /Directory/dir1/dir2/x.jpg and /Directory/dir1/y.jpg), it looks pretty good to me (though the `-r` is unnecessary).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about:

```
find /Directory -name \*.jpg -exec mv {} /Directory \;
```

That should work.